# Oracle repeated function calls in select and where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle SQL query

```
select /*+ORDERED */ payr.payroll_name payroll_name,
       nvl(papf.employee_number, papf.npw_number) employee_number,
       nvl
       (
          xxpay_util.safe_to_number
          (
             xxpay_util_element.get_run_result
             (
                p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
                p_payroll_id         => paaf.payroll_id,          -- in     number
                p_payroll_action_id  => null,                     -- in     number,
                p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
                p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
                p_element_name_regex => '^Disability Cover ER$',   -- in     varchar2 '^Disability Cover ER Opt Out$'
                p_input_value        => 'Pay Value',             -- in     varchar2
                p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
                p_aggregation        => 'sum',                   -- in     varchar2
                p_round              => 2                        -- in     number default 2
             )
          ),
          0
       )  disability_benefit,
       nvl
       (
          xxpay_util.safe_to_number
          (
             xxpay_util_element.get_run_result
             (
                p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
                p_payroll_id         => paaf.payroll_id,          -- in     number
                p_payroll_action_id  => null,                     -- in     number,
                p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
                p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
                p_element_name_regex => '^Death Cover ER Opt Out$',   -- in     varchar2
                p_input_value        => 'Pay Value',             -- in     varchar2
                p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
                p_aggregation        => 'sum',                   -- in     varchar2
                p_round              => 2                        -- in     number default 2
             )
          ),
          0
       )  death_cover,
       nvl
       (
          xxpay_util.safe_to_number
          (
             xxpay_util_element.get_run_result
             (
                p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
                p_payroll_id         => paaf.payroll_id,          -- in     number
                p_payroll_action_id  => null,                     -- in     number,
                p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
                p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
                p_element_name_regex => '^Funeral Cover ER$',   -- in     varchar2 '^Funeral Cover ER Opt Out$'
                p_input_value        => 'Pay Value',             -- in     varchar2
                p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
                p_aggregation        => 'sum',                   -- in     varchar2
                p_round              => 2                        -- in     number default 2
             )
          ),
          0
       )  funeral_cover,
       ppos.actual_termination_date termination_date       
from   (
          select ptp.payroll_id, 
                 min(ptp.start_date) real_month_start,
                 max(ptp.end_date)   real_month_end
          from   per_time_periods ptp
          where  decode(ptp.prd_information_category, 'ZA', to_char(ptp.pay_advice_date, 'yyyymm'), to_char(ptp.regular_payment_date, 'yyyymm')) = '201612'  
          group  by ptp.payroll_id
       )  mon,
       pay_all_payrolls_f           payr,
       per_all_assignments_f        paaf,
       per_periods_of_service       ppos,
       per_people_f                 papf,
       per_business_groups          pbg,
       hr_all_organization_units    haou,
       per_jobs                     pj,
       pay_cost_allocation_keyflex  pcak       
where  payr.payroll_id = mon.payroll_id 
and    mon.real_month_end between payr.effective_start_date and payr.effective_end_date
and    paaf.payroll_id = mon.payroll_id
and    paaf.assignment_type = 'E'
and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y'
and    paaf.effective_start_date =
(
   select max(paaf2.effective_start_date)
   from   per_all_assignments_f paaf2
   where  paaf2.assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id
   and    paaf2.assignment_type = 'E'
   and    paaf2.primary_flag = 'Y'
   and    paaf2.payroll_id = mon.payroll_id
   and    mon.real_month_start <= paaf2.effective_end_date
   and    mon.real_month_end   >= paaf2.effective_start_date
)
and    ppos.period_of_service_id = paaf.period_of_service_id
and    mon.real_month_start <= nvl(ppos.actual_termination_date, to_date('31/12/4712', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
and    mon.real_month_end   >= ppos.date_start
and    papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
and    papf.effective_start_date =
(
   select max(papf2.effective_start_date)
   from   per_all_people_f papf2
   where  papf2.person_id = paaf.person_id
   and    mon.real_month_start <= papf2.effective_end_date
   and    mon.real_month_end   >= papf2.effective_start_date
)
and    pbg.business_group_id = paaf.business_group_id
and    haou.organization_id (+) = paaf.organization_id
and    pj.job_id (+) = paaf.job_id
and    pcak.cost_allocation_keyflex_id (+) = haou.cost_allocation_keyflex_id
and
(
   nvl
   (
      xxpay_util.safe_to_number
      (
         xxpay_util_element.get_run_result
         (
            p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
            p_payroll_id         => paaf.payroll_id,          -- in     number
            p_payroll_action_id  => null,                     -- in     number,
            p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
            p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
            p_element_name_regex => '^Disability Cover ER$',   -- in     varchar2   -- Disability Cover ER Opt Out
            p_input_value        => 'Pay Value',             -- in     varchar2
            p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
            p_aggregation        => 'sum',                   -- in     varchar2
            p_round              => 2                        -- in     number default 2
         )
      ),
      0
   )
   +
   nvl
   (
      xxpay_util.safe_to_number
      (
         xxpay_util_element.get_run_result
         (
            p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
            p_payroll_id         => paaf.payroll_id,          -- in     number
            p_payroll_action_id  => null,                     -- in     number,
            p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
            p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
            p_element_name_regex => '^Death Cover ER Opt Out$',   -- in     varchar2
            p_input_value        => 'Pay Value',             -- in     varchar2
            p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
            p_aggregation        => 'sum',                   -- in     varchar2
            p_round              => 2                        -- in     number default 2
         )
      ),
      0
   )
   +
   nvl
   (
      xxpay_util.safe_to_number
      (
         xxpay_util_element.get_run_result
         (
            p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
            p_payroll_id         => paaf.payroll_id,          -- in     number
            p_payroll_action_id  => null,                     -- in     number,
            p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
            p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
            p_element_name_regex => '^Funeral Cover ER$',   -- in     varchar2  -- Funeral Cover ER Opt Out
            p_input_value        => 'Pay Value',             -- in     varchar2
            p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
            p_aggregation        => 'sum',                   -- in     varchar2
            p_round              => 2                        -- in     number default 2
         )
      ),
      0
   )
)  != 0
and    nvl
       (
          xxpay_util_element.get_element_entry
          (
             p_business_group_id  => paaf.business_group_id,   -- in     number
             p_start_period       => mon.real_month_start,     -- in     date
             p_end_period         => mon.real_month_end,       -- in     date
             p_element_name_regex => '^Retirement Fund Opt In$',   -- in     varchar2
             p_input_value        => 'Opt In or Out',         -- in     varchar2
             p_assignment_id      => paaf.assignment_id,      -- in     number
             p_aggregation        => 'none',                  -- in     varchar2
             p_round              => 0                        -- in     number default 2
          ),
          '$XXX$'
       )  in ('NC', 'OUT')
and    exists
(
   select 1
   from   pay_payroll_actions    ppap,
          pay_assignment_actions paap,
          pay_action_interlocks  pai,
          pay_assignment_actions paar,
          pay_payroll_actions    ppar,
          per_time_periods       ptp
   where  ppap.action_type in ('P', 'U')
   and    ppap.action_status = 'C'
   and    paap.payroll_action_id = ppap.payroll_action_id
   and    paap.action_status = 'C'
   and    pai.locking_action_id = paap.assignment_action_id
   and    paar.assignment_action_id = pai.locked_action_id  
   and    ppar.payroll_action_id = paar.payroll_action_id
   and    ppar.action_type in ('R', 'Q')
   and    ptp.time_period_id = ppar.time_period_id
   and    decode(ptp.prd_information_category, 'ZA', to_char(ptp.pay_advice_date, 'yyyymm'), to_char(ptp.regular_payment_date, 'yyyymm')) = '201612'
   and    paap.assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id
   and    paar.assignment_id = paaf.assignment_id
)
order  by pcak.segment2, papf.employee_number, paaf.assignment_number
```

Is there a way to rewrite the query so that the function calls from the select clause (`xxpay_util_element.get_run_result`) that is repeated in the where clause are not repeated and only called once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try creating this sql as subquery  and add where clause in parent query :

```
Select * from (
   select  
         xxpay_util_element.get_run_result as get_run_result_1, --only fetch values here
          .......
   from .....

 )
 where get_run_result_1 ......... --add where clause here
```

Comment: Strangely enough it runs a lot slower as a sub query. I guess it was clever enough to first eliminate the ones that add up to zero.

Comment: This approach will not work reliably.  With predicate pushing and other Oracle optimizer transformations it is possible that Oracle will re-write the query.  Without hints or specific features there is no guarantee that an inline view will run first.  The query may work today but it may not work tomorrow.